# Can't get past beta password screen from Blackberry

Tags: bug, status-declined

While this only matters for a couple of weeks, it seems impossible to visit superuser.com as it won't go process the beta entrance code.

Comment: do you have all cookies enabled?

Comment: yes I do, the "Grant Access" button doesn't seem to do anything at all

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the `Grant Access` button doesn't actually do anything, and even in a real browser it doesn't have a cursor change which is quite annoying. However, you *can* still login by pressing enter in the password field -- I just tried :)